# How to add sum of annotate to a column of the original model

Tags: sql, django, django-models, group-by, sum

Example model:

```
class Cluster(models.Model):
    index = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cluster_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    module_count = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I know I can get the groupby sum of a django model with:

```
    cluster_id | module_count 
    -------------------------
    1          | 1
    1          | 2
    2          | 3
    2          | 1
 

    sum_mods = clusters.values('cluster_id').annotate(data_sum=Sum('module_count'))


    cluster_id | module_count 
    -------------------------
    1          | 3
    2          | 4
```

This would give me the sum of each group of grouped by cluster_id.

How can I assing this sum to a column in the original model ? Such as:

```
    cluster_id | module_count | data_sum 
    ----------------------------------------
    1          | 1            |3
    1          | 2            |3
    2          | 3            |4
    2          | 1            |4
```

Comment: add your models

Comment: Model added on top

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
clusters.values('cluster_id').update(data_sum=Sum('module_count'))
```

Comment: This gives an "Aggregate functions are not allowed in this query" error

Answer (score 0):

```
pk_list = list(set(Cluster.objects.all().values_list('cluster_id', flat=True)))
#return list of all unique cluster_id

for pk in pk_list:
    #get all cluster with this id
    lst = Cluster.objects.filter(cluster_id=pk)

    #get sum of all module_count
    sum_col = lst.aggregate(sum_col=Sum('module_count'))['sum_col']

    #update  all cluster with sum_col
    lst.update(module_count=sum_col)
```

Comment: I get: AttributeError: 'OuterRef' object has no attribute 'annotate'

Comment: Sorry I ment "AttributeError: 'OuterRef' object has no attribute 'aggregate'"

Comment: yeah sorry , missing one bracket , i edit my post , check now ;)

Comment: No luck yet: ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.

Comment: i have update it and is work ( tested with fake db and your model), is not relay optimized ( many sql request , i will try other "exotic" query), i come back if a find best solutions ;)